# Create table from Excel file

Tags: sql, excel, vb.net

I'm trying to create a temp table on my database from an Excel file uploaded by the user. I cannot understand where is the problem and why Visual Studio is throwing that exception.

**Code**

```
  Private Sub Excel_Load(ByVal filePath As String)
    Dim myConn As SqlConnection
    Dim myCmd As SqlCommand
    Dim sqlCmd As String

    Dim filename As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath)

    'Setting up Connection'
    myConn = New SqlConnection("Server=*****;Database=*****;User ID=*****;Password=*****;Integrated Security=SSPI;")
    myConn.Open()

    'Create table'
    sqlCmd = "CREATE TABLE XlsTemp AS (SELECT * FROM EXCELLINK [" & filename & "$])"

    'Execute Query'
    myCmd = myConn.CreateCommand()
    myCmd.CommandText = sqlCmd
    myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    myConn.Close()
End Sub
```

**Exception**

> SqlException: The object name 'EXCELLINK' is not valid.

*Peu_UNRAE* is my Excel file.

Comment: The inner query would evaluate to `Select * From Excellink [myfile.xlsx$]` I am not sure about VBA but it does look weird.

Comment: Found it on support.ms

Comment: What has visual studio to do with this? These might help https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/306397/how-to-use-excel-with-sql-server-linked-servers-and-distributed-querie   and  https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/321686/how-to-import-data-from-excel-to-sql-server

Comment: After you have configured the workbook, then the three (3) periods after Excellink are important >> "FROM EXCELLINK...[myfile.xlsx$]"

Comment: @donPablo at the end I figure it out how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I come up with this solution:

```
  Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
  Dim fileExcelType As String

  //Get the file extension in order to use the propper provider
  If IO.Path.GetExtension(fileExcel.ToUpper) = ".XLS" Then
     fileExcelType = "Excel 8.0"
     MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" & fileExcel & "';Extended Properties=" & fileExcelType & ";")
  Else
     fileExcelType = "Excel 12.0"
     MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & fileExcel & "';Extended Properties=" & fileExcelType & ";")
  End If

  //Opening excel connection
  MyConnection.Open()

  Dim myTableName = MyConnection.GetSchema("Tables").Rows(0)("TABLE_NAME")
  Dim MyCommand As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}] ", myTableName), MyConnection)
  MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "    ")
  MyCommand.Fill(dt)

  //Closing connection
  MyConnection.Close()
```

***Remarks:***

I used `//` for the comments because the standar `'` was giving some problem here on StackOverflow

Comment: @PatrickHonorez now for SO they are a String, I don't know why it does this weird thing on this post, because I always used only one `'` at the start of the link for a comment and it always worked.